# Virtual environment в Pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

новичок в программировании.
Прохожу курс по созданию веб-приложений с помощью Django.
Пишу все это дело в Pycharm Pro.
Я немного запутался и не понимаю в чем разница : при создании  нового проекта в Django есть 2 опции: new environment using venv или же previously configured interpreter т.е python 3.9.
В чем выгода создания venv?
[image: пикча]

Comment: Смотрите, когда у Вас используется venv - то все "зависимости" Вашего проекта устанавливаются локально (относительно Вашего проекта). Грубо говоря, вы запустили проект, добавили в него какие то зависимости, потом перешли в другой проект с другим venv - а там этих зависимостей нет. Это важно, когда Вам надо на одном компьютере использовать разные наборы библиотек или разные версии. То есть, venv - это "про изоляцию конфигураций отдельных проектов друг от друга". Думаю, что мой комментарий не тянет на полноценный ответ, но надеюсь, что так стало понятнее

Comment: Думаю что понял вас, спасибо.